# Как сделать измену текста в sql

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, telegram-bot

Ка сделать так, чтобы "душа" менялась на человек

```
import telebot
import sqlite3
from random import randint

bot = telebot.TeleBot('1822313271:AAG2A4_0WmRtXpoounFEUn79vp4X_v_n2sk')


db = sqlite3.connect('game.db', check_same_thread=False)
cu = db.cursor()

cu.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    user_id INT,
    rasa TEXT
)""")
db.commit()


balance = 0
opt = 0


@bot.message_handler(commands=["reg"])
def echo_all(message):
    cu.execute("SELECT * FORM user WHERE user_id = ?", [message.from_user.id])
    if cu.fetchone() is None:
        cu.execute("INSERT INTO user (user_id, rasa) VALUES (?, ?)", [message.from_user.id, 'Человек'])
        db.commit()

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{message.from_user.first_name}, я успешно запомнил ваше имя!!')
        rs = cu.fetchone()
        if rs:
            rasa = rs[0]


@bot.message_handler(commands=["rasa"])
def send_profile(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f"[Система]Какую расу вы хотите выбрать?")


@bot.message_handler(commands=["rasa1"])
def send_profile(message):
    cu.execute("UPDATE user SET rasa=? WHERE user_id=?", ['Эльф', message.from_user.id])
    db.commit()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f"[Система]Вы выбрали расу эльф")


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать в мир Казинус!")


@bot.message_handler(commands=["help"])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"[Система]Все команды в игре:\nСистемные команды:\n/reg - открывает регистрацию персонажа\n/rasa - вы выбираете расу для своего персонажа\nИгровые команды:\n/profile - открывает профиль")


@bot.message_handler(commands=["profile"])
def send_profile(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"[Система]Имя персонажа: {message.from_user.first_name}\nРаса персонажа: {rasa}\nДеньги персонажа:{balance}\n")


bot.polling()
```

Comment: Метка sql базы правильно указана? :)

Comment: @gil9red Заметил, спасибо)

Comment: а после обновлений рассы вы сохранили изминения через db.commit()?, просто у вас в коде не вижу

Comment: @DisanD_08 Да, сохраняется

Comment: @FiolDoll ну лично я делаю через format, так что думаю я вам ничем не помогу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте биндинг-параметров в запросе:

```
cu.execute("UPDATE user SET rasa=? WHERE user_id=?", ['Человек', message.from_user.id])
```

Еще тут нужно добавить запятую:

```
cu.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    user_id INT,
    rasa Text
)""")
db.commit()
```

Проверил работу:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('game.db', check_same_thread=False)
cu = db.cursor()

cu.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    user_id INT,
    rasa Text
)""")
db.commit()

cu.execute("INSERT INTO user (user_id, rasa) VALUES (?, ?)", [123, 'душа'])

cu.execute("UPDATE user SET rasa=? WHERE user_id=?", ['Человек', 123])

cu.execute("SELECT rasa FROM user WHERE user_id = ?", [123])
rs = cu.fetchone()
if rs:
    rasa = rs[0]
    print(rasa)

db.commit()
```

В SQLite Studio:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: rasa

Comment: @FiolDoll, проверьте что в таблице user есть это поле. Если вы ранее создали таблицу, то изменения полей в `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` не поменяет таблицу

Comment: Сработало, но выводится  душа

Comment: @FiolDoll, у меня код работает, как видно по скриншотам. Убедитесь, что вызывается коммит и что в UPDATE передаются правильные поля

Comment: Попробовал ваш код в отдельном пустом проекте. Работает. Но когда я вставляю код в основной(который выше) не работает

Comment: Ок, покажите ваш текущий код, включая правки из моего решения. Добавьте это в **UPD** в вашем вопросе :)

Comment: Готово, полный код добавлен в UPD

Comment: @FiolDoll, `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"[Система]Имя персонажа: {message.from_user.first_name}\nРаса персонажа: {rasa}\nДеньги персонажа:{balance}\n")` а почему тут раса не из таблицы базы достается? И тут `if cu.fetchone() is None:` странно условие, не вижу самого запроса, наверное должен был быть выше какой-нибудь SELECT, где проверяется такой user_id

Comment: Насчёт rasa, я не имею представления как брать информацию из Бд, а про fetchone не понял

Comment: @FiolDoll, у вас user_id не является первичным ключом и не является уникальным, поэтому возможны дубликаты в таблице по `user_id`. Насчет проверки с `cu.fetchone()`, перед ней нужно сделать запрос вида: `cu.execute("SELECT * FORM user WHERE user_id = ?", [message.from_user.id])`, тогда можно будет убедиться что юзер будет добавлен только один раз (но я бы лучше в id PRIMARY KEY складывал id юзеров)

Comment: @FiolDoll, ок, добавил пример SELECT и извлечения rasa

Comment: Не совсем понимаю куда что вставлять. Всё слишком запутанно. Именно не у вас, а у меня. Кстати, может ли повлиять то, что в SQlliteStudio ничего не записывается? А ещё, я изменил свой "код"

Comment: @FiolDoll, эххх нужно матчасть знать :) Сделали бы примеры с sqlite3 без бота, а после добавили в бота. Нужно сложную задачу делить по частям и их решать. Показываю пример: https://pastebin.com/QpS4DA45

Comment: Уж понял, что задача сложная :) В любом случае, спасибо

Comment: @FiolDoll, пожалуйста :) Кст, чтобы не мучиться с формированием sql-запросов можно попробовать работать через ORM, типа peewee или sqlalchemy